# Discovery mechanism of different DDS vendor

Tags: wireshark, publish-subscribe, vendor, discovery, data-distribution-service

I am new to data distributed service (DDS) and learning about it. I have come across this [document](https://community.rti.com/howto/how-determine-wireshark-when-discovery-completed) of RTI DDS about how to determine discovery time using Wireshark. 
My questions are:

1. Is the discovery mechanism the same in others DDS vendors?
2. If no, is it any possible way to know others DDS vendors discovery mechanism? Because it seems like only RTI discusses about this problem.

Any answer, suggestion, hint or link is welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the spec.  RTPS (real-time publish/subscribe) Discovery via UDP is part of the specification, so any vendor who claims to provide OMG-DDS as per the standard, must provide that mechanism.  The vendors have "plug fests" where they run their own DDS implementation and show interoperability with the other vendors' implementations.  This is done using the Shapes demo.

Now:  The spec *only* describes the Discovery over UDP mechanism.

Each vendor is free to implement *other* discovery mechanisms, over UDP or other transports.

Non-standard discovery over TCP, over shared memory constructs, even non-standard over UDP, etc are all available depending on the vendor, and for the most part these are **not** interoperable between vendors.

The RTI doc is valid for other vendors' OMG-DDS Standard UDP Discovery also, since the (RTI supplied) Wireshark dissector used is an RTPS protocol dissector, not "an RTI protocol" dissector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That is really clear to me.